# For loop and getchar/putchar usage in C

Tags: c

I'm quite new to C and I'm trying to write a loop that takes input with `getchar`, then print only the U's and K's from the input using `putchar`.

I tried this:

```
printf("Enter a bunch of letters: ");

char ch;
while (ch != 'x') {
    ch = getchar();
    if ( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        putchar(ch - 32);
        ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would be able to help you more if you show us some code; what have you tried?

Comment: I added my code now. I'm quite new to C so I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: that code is completely irrelevant with your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're trying to read input until 'x' is entered, then print the U's and K's from said input. Try this.

Per your comment, seems like you want to print them as upper whether or not they're read as upper. You can use `tolower()` for that.

```
char ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != 'x')
    if (toupper(ch) == 'U' || toupper(ch) == 'K')
        putchar(toupper(ch));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was quite the answer I was looking for. Though I do wonder how to convert the characters I get using putchar to uppercase.

Comment: @Sinem I'm guessing by that you mean you want to ignore the case of the characters and print them as uppercase? I'll update to include that.

Comment: yes sir, thanks a lot. I really learned that now, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("(I will print U and K only): ");
    int c;
    while(EOF != (c=getchar())){
        if(c=='U'||c=='K')
            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks very alike to the other answer, also the one I was quite looking for.